# attributeError("'_AssertRaisesContext' object has no attribute 'exception'",),

Tags: python

I'm a beginner coding in python. I really don't understand what this error refers to. Any help will be greatly appreciated.
the code is supposed to calculate the taxes of people in a certain country as follows:
Yearly Income: 0 - 1000

Tax Rate: 0%

Yearly Income: 1,001 - 10,000

Tax Rate: 10%

Yearly Income: 10,001 - 20,200

Tax Rate: 15%

Yearly Income: 20,201 - 30,750

Tax Rate: 20%

Yearly Income: 30,751 - 50,000

Tax Rate: 25%

Yearly Income: Over 50,000

Tax Rate: 30%

my code:

```
def calculate_tax(pDict):
  if type(pDict) is dict:
    try:
      length = len(pDict)
      count = 0
      #decleration of new updated dictionary
      dict_list = {}
      while count<length:
        #calculate yearly tax
        #countdown of values in the dictionary until the last value
        totals = list(pDict.values())[count]
        totals = int(totals)
        names = list(pDict.keys())[count]
        #decleration of variable to store tax
        tTax = 0
        if totals < 1000:
          tTax = totals * 0
        elif totals > 1000 and totals<= 10000:
          tTax = 1000 * 0
          totals = totals - 1000
          tTax = tTax + totals * 0.1
        elif totals > 10000 and totals <=20200:
          tTax = 1000 * 0
          tTax = tTax + 9000 * 0.1
          totals=totals-10000
          tTax = tTax + totals * 0.15
        elif totals >20200 and totals <= 30750:
          tTax = 1000 * 0
          tTax = tTax + 9000 * 0.1
          tTax = tTax + 10200 * 0.15
          totals=totals-20200
          tTax = tTax + totals * 0.2
        elif totals>30750 and totals<=50000:
          tTax = 1000 * 0
          tTax = tTax + 9000 * 0.1
          tTax = tTax + 10200 * 0.15
          tTax = tTax + 10550 * 0.2
          totals=totals-30750
          tTax = tTax + totals * 0.25
        else:
          tTax = 1000 * 0
          tTax = tTax + 9000 * 0.1
          tTax = tTax + 10200 * 0.15
          tTax = tTax + 10550 * 0.2
          tTax = tTax + 19250 * 0.25
          totals=totals-50000
          tTax = tTax + totals * 0.3
        dict_list.setdefault(names,tTax)
        count = count + 1
      return dict_list
    except(attributeError,TypeError):
      raise ValueError('The provided input is not a dictionary')
  else:
    print("only dict type values allowed")
```

the code used to test if my code works:

```
from unittest import TestCase

    class CalculateTaxTests(TestCase):
      def test_it_calculates_tax_for_one_person(self):
        result = calculate_tax({"James": 20500})
        self.assertEqual(result, {"James": 2490.0}, msg="Should return {'James': 2490.0} for the input {'James': 20500}")

      def test_it_calculates_tax_for_several_people(self):
        income_input = {"James": 20500, "Mary": 500, "Evan": 70000}
        result = calculate_tax(income_input)
        self.assertEqual({"James": 2490.0, "Mary": 0, "Evan": 15352.5}, result,
          msg="Should return {} for the input {}".format(
                {"James": 2490.0, "Mary": 0, "Evan": 15352.5},
                {"James": 20500, "Mary": 500, "Evan": 70000}
          )
        )

      def test_it_does_not_accept_integers(self):
        with self.assertRaises(ValueError) as context:
          calculate_tax(1)
          self.assertEqual(
            "The provided input is not a dictionary.",
            context.exception.message, "Invalid input of type int not allowed"
          )

      def test_calculated_tax_is_a_float(self):
        result = calculate_tax({"Jane": 20500})
        self.assertIsInstance(
          calculate_tax({"Jane": 20500}), dict, msg="Should return a result of data type dict")
        self.assertIsInstance(result["Jane"], float, msg="Tax returned should be an float.")

      def test_it_returns_zero_tax_for_income_less_than_1000(self):
        result = calculate_tax({"Jake": 100})
        self.assertEqual(result, {"Jake": 0}, msg="Should return zero tax for incomes less than 1000")

      def test_it_throws_an_error_if_any_of_the_inputs_is_non_numeric(self):
        with self.assertRaises(ValueError, msg='Allow only numeric input'):
          calculate_tax({"James": 2490.0, "Kiura": '200', "Kinuthia": 15352.5})

      def test_it_return_an_empty_dict_for_an_empty_dict_input(self):
        result = calculate_tax({})
        self.assertEqual(result, {}, msg='Should return an empty dict if the input was an empty dict')
```

Please help:-)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

For reference, the complete exception message from the failing test is as follows:

```
ERROR: test_it_does_not_accept_integers (__main__.CalculateTaxTests)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "calculate_tax_test.py", line 27, in test_it_does_not_accept_integers
    context.exception.message, "Invalid input of type int not allowed"
AttributeError: '_AssertRaisesContext' object has no attribute 'exception'
```

The failing test is this:

```
      def test_it_does_not_accept_integers(self):
        with self.assertRaises(ValueError) as context:
          calculate_tax(1)
          self.assertEqual(
            "The provided input is not a dictionary.",
            context.exception.message, "Invalid input of type int not allowed"
          )
```

The problem is that the assertion after `calculate_tax` is in the wrong place.  If an exception is raised in `calculate_tax`, the assertion will be skipped.  If no exception is raised, the assertion will fail.  The assertion will therefore never pass.

The fix is to un-indent the assertion to move it out of the `with` statement.  For clarity I've also inserted a blank line:

```
      def test_it_does_not_accept_integers(self):
        with self.assertRaises(ValueError) as context:
          calculate_tax(1)

        self.assertEqual(
          "The provided input is not a dictionary.",
          context.exception.message, "Invalid input of type int not allowed"
        )
```

The `with self.assertRaises(...)` statement can catch an exception if one gets raised by the call to `calculate_tax`.  If this happens, the exception detail is then left in `context`, and your assertion would then be able to test whether the exception was as you expected.

However, even after making this change, the test still fails, because `calculate_tax(1)` doesn't raise a `ValueError`.  I'll leave it up to you to fix this.